# Dozer: change the field name strategy

Tags: java, dozer

As you know, dozer use same field name to mapping between two beans, but how can I just simple change this mapping strategy.

```
public class Product {
   private String productName;

   public String getProductName(){
       return productName;
   }

   public void setProductName(String productName){
       this.productName = productName;
   }
}

public class ProductTO {
   private String PRODUCT_NAME;

   public String getPRODUCT_NAME(){
        return PRODUCT_NAME;
   }

   public void setPRODUCT_NAME(String PRODUCT_NAME){
        this.PRODUCT_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME;
   }
}
```

For above case, I don't want to define a mapping file, because too much field and too much TO, I just want to change the default mapping strategy, and update to like above: thisField = THIS_FIELD.
Thanks if you have any suggestion.

Comment: You can't create a generic function to place an underscore somewhere between words. You could create one to convert the fields from lowercase to uppercase though, but it wouldn't be efficient.
I'm thinking of a dozer custom converter and reflection.
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html

Answer (score 1):

Dozer doesn't support this. May be you can request this feature for future release.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Orika](https://github.com/orika-mapper) it provide similar feature and a more advanced way to manage mapping, [Advanced Mapping](http://orika-mapper.github.com/orika-docs/advanced-mappings.html)

Second way to do that is to use MappingHints

[Example of MappingHint usage](https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika/blob/master/tests/src/main/java/ma/glasnost/orika/test/hint/DefaultMappingHintTestCase.java#L92)